# Uniform convergence of indicators

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of real-valued functions converging uniformly to a function $f(x)$ and let $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0$.
Is it necessarily true that the sequence of (extended real-valued) functions
$$
g_n(x)\triangleq \frac{1}{\epsilon_n}I_{\{
f_x(x)>\epsilon_n
\}}
$$
converges uniformly to the  (extended real-valued) function
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 g(x)\triangleq & \begin{cases}
 \infty & \mbox{if} & f(x)>0\\
 0 & \mbox{if} & f(x)=0?
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
If not what additional conditions must I impose for this to be true?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider $\epsilon_n = 2^{-n}$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$.  Then $g_n(x) = 2^n$ everywhere, but $g(x) = 0$ everywhere.  You need $\epsilon_n$ to converge to $0$ faster than $f_n$ where $f(x)=0$.  I don't know of a simple sufficient condition.

Comment: So if I choose $\epsilon_n$ to be of higher order of convergence than $f_n$ then I'll be ok?